# Form validation with model but no table in cakePHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp-2.0

I have a form that requires that all fields are filled in.

Upon submit, it should validate, before doing anything else. However, it submits even if there are some fields that were not filled in.

I've searched on here, but can't seem to find anything that is off use for me.

Here is my method in my `InductionPpe` controller:

```
public function request() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->InductionPpe->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->InductionPpe->validates()) {
            // carry on
        } else {
            $this->validateErrors($this->InductionPpe);
            $this->render();
        }
    }
}
```

My model has all the rules for the fields set up and completes the rest of the process just fine. But it does not validate.

Where do I start looking for the issue? And how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Validation rules in the InductionPpe Model:

```
class InductionPpe extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'hr_employee_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric')
            ),
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your name.'
            ),
        ),
        'shoes' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the shoe size required.'
            ),
        ),
        'reflective_jacket' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the size reflective jacket required.'
            ),
        ),
        'metaguards' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the size of metaguards required.'
            ),
        ),
        'glasses' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the number of glasses required.'
            ),
        ),
        'earplugs' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the amount of earplugs reguired.'
            ),
        ),
        'hardhats' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the amount of hardhats required.'
            ),
        ),
        'gloves' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the amount of gloves required.'
            ),
        ),
        'kit_bags' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the amount of kit bags required.'
            ),
        ),
        'dust_mask' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the amount of dust masks required.'
            ),
        ),
        'ppe_size' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the size of the PPE items.'
            ),
        ),
        'activities' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please specify which activities the PPE items are required for.'
            ),
        ),
        'site' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the site that you will be visiting.'
            ),
        ),
        'project_number' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the project number applicable.'
            ),
        ),
        'date_required' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter the date that the PPE equipment is required.'
            ),
        )
    );
```

}

**UPDATE 2**

This is the validation debug I get (if I run `debug($this->InductionPpe->validationErrors);`).

```
array(
    'name' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter your name.'
    ),
    'shoes' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the shoe size required.'
    ),
    'reflective_jacket' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the size reflective jacket required.'
    ),
    'metaguards' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the size of metaguards required.'
    ),
    'glasses' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the number of glasses required.'
    ),
    'earplugs' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the amount of earplugs reguired.'
    ),
    'hardhats' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the amount of hardhats required.'
    ),
    'gloves' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the amount of gloves required.'
    ),
    'kit_bags' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the amount of kit bags required.'
    ),
    'dust_mask' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the amount of dust masks required.'
    ),
    'ppe_size' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the size of the PPE items.'
    ),
    'activities' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please specify which activities the PPE items are required for.'
    ),
    'site' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the site that you will be visiting.'
    ),
    'project_number' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the project number applicable.'
    ),
    'date_required' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Please enter the date that the PPE equipment is required.'
    )
)
```

And my form where these are entered:

```
<div class="inductionPpes form">
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('PpeRequest',array('type' => 'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('&emsp;PPE Request'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name',array('value'=>$loggedInUsersName));
            echo $this->Form->input('shoes');
            echo $this->Form->input('reflective_jacket');
            echo $this->Form->input('metaguards');
            echo $this->Form->input('glasses');
            echo $this->Form->input('earplugs');
            echo $this->Form->input('hardhats');
            echo $this->Form->input('gloves');
            echo $this->Form->input('kit_bag');
            echo $this->Form->input('dust_masks');
            echo $this->Form->input('ppe_size');
            echo $this->Form->input('activities',array('label'=>'Type of activities that will be undertaken'));
            echo $this->Form->input('additional',array('label'=>'Additional PPE Requirements'));
            echo $this->Form->input('site',array('label'=>'Type of Site'));
            echo $this->Form->input('project_number');
            echo $this->Form->input('date_required');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the validation rules of your model to see if the problem is there please.

Comment: Added the validation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the *notempty* rule to this

```
'notempty' => array(
    'required' => true,
    'allowEmpty' => false, // this may not be neccessary
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',  
    'message' => 'Please enter the ...',
)
```

The problem may be that you wrapped validation rule names in an array. AFAIK only rules with parameters should be entered this way.

Also I don't know about `$this->validateErrors` and whether such variable exists but I always use `$this->Model->validationErrors`

Comment: Okay this works. Thank you very much. It does not display that block around the input that says that this field is required. How do I do that?

Comment: You are welcome. This should be done automaticaly unless you changed the error option for an input or inputDefaults option for an entire form, can you show me your view with the form? You might try to do it manually by placing this in your view `echo $this->Form->error('field_name');` Make sure the field name is the same you use for creating the input.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried typing in all the fields and it does not work. When I ebug validation errors, it returns errors on ALL my fields, stating the custom error message that I entered.

Comment: Well to figure this one out I'd need to see the debug output of validation errors along with the form you are creating in your view.

Comment: Ok, I believe I got it... change this `echo $this->Form->create('PpeRequest',array('type' => 'file'));` to this `echo $this->Form->create('InductionPpe',array('type' => 'file'));` and let me know if that worked out. If for some reason this won't work, try the `$this->Form->error(..)` I mentioned earlier

Comment: I actually missed the array('type'=>'file')... WTF was it doing there... Anyway, it marks the fields now, but still marks all of them.

Comment: Thats because of **PpeRequest** in your Form->create() method. All your inputs are submitted with key **PpeRequest.field_name** and therefore they only can save&validate on PpeRequest model, InductionPpe ignores them. Either you prefix all your input methods key params with InductionPpe so `echo $this->Form->input('hardhats');` becomes `echo $this->Form->input('InductionPpe.hardhats');` or you change the Form->create() method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30117/discussion-between-darkranger-and-volaju-ma-lubos)

Comment: Nevermind, fixed the issue, seems it's that $this->render line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with all your notempty validations)

```
'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please enter your name.',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
    ),
```

putting `required` and `allowEmpty` on bottom. Also, reading your comments, you mention the error blocks doesn't show. Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382257/cakephp-validation-not-working), if you do $this->Model->save(), it'll take care of that, otherwise you'll have to do it.