# CakePHP 2.x validating form

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP and I have followed tutorial from their www. Now I'm making simple application and I stuck in validating form, I read about validating form [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html).

**Controller**:

```
class DevicesController extends AppController {
   public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
   public $components = array('Session');

   public function add()
   {
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Device->create();
        $this->Device->set($this->request->data);

        if ($this->Device->validates()) {
                if ($this->Device->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('feedback'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                // didn't validate logic
                $this->Session->setFlash($this->Device->validationErrors);
                }
        }

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('feedback'));
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
class Device extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
    'user' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule'    => array('between', 5, 15),
            'message' => 'Between 5 to 15 characters'
        )
    ),
    'manufacturer' => array(
        'rule'       => 'date',
        'message'    => 'Enter a valid date',
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
    'mac' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Nick name is required.'
        )
    )
);}
```

**View**:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Device');
echo $this->Form->input('user', array('label' => 'Urzytkownik'));
echo $this->Form->input('mac', array('label' => 'MAC'));
echo $this->Form->input('manufacturer', array('label' => 'Producent'));
```

Even when I will not fill the form it successfully passed validation process.
What I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of approach is wrong here..

You'll get validation errors in else block of `validates` once validation fails. but you're accessing it in validates block itself which is incorrect.

it should be like this.

```
if ($this->Device->validates()) {
    // successful validation
} else {
    // you'll get the validation errors here
}
```

Now the resultant code should be

```
if ($this->Device->validates()) {
    if ($this->Device->save($this->request->data, false)) { // setting 2nd param to false thus no need to validate again.
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('feedback'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } 
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $this->Session->setFlash($this->Device->validationErrors);
}
```

Comment: Ok i found answer, my file in model had "s" : Devices insted of Device, by removing s everything works

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
if ($this->Device->validates()) {
    if ($this->Device->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('feedback'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        // didn't validate logic
        $this->Session->setFlash($this->Device->validationErrors);
    }
} else {       
    $errors = $this->Device->validationErrors;
}
```

Refer : [CakePHP validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382257/cakephp-validation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
if ($this->Device->save($this->request->data)) {
```

after already validating doesn't make sense.

Either do it together in one simple call:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Device->create();
    if ($this->Device->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('feedback'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    // didn't validate logic - note that validationErrors is an array!
    $this->Session->setFlash($this->Device->validationErrors);
}
```

or use save correctly in this case:

```
$this->Device->save(null, false)
```

(to avoid secondary validation).

Note: The first is the cleaner option.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try the code.....**

<?php
if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
                $this->Device->create();
                       if ($this->Device->save($this->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Data has been save.'));
}
}
 ?>
```